# how to get Emacs Dired to use case-insensitive alphabetical order

Tags: emacs, dired

How do I get Emacs Dired to list my files in case-insensitive alphabetical order?

Comment: If you can get `ls` to list the files in the order you want, you can customize `dired-listing-switches` and get the same order in dired.  Not sure if `ls` has an option for that, though...

Comment: @legoscia: +1, GNU `ls` has `--group-directories-first`, however, there will be no luck with other versions of `ls`.

Comment: OK so how do I get OSX bash to get `ls` to list files case-insensitively?

Comment: Here is a link to the `ls` man page for OSX 10.9: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html and here is one for general flavors of Linux / Unix:  http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uls.htm

Comment: @lawlist that man page doesn't say anything about case insensitivity

Comment: That may be the answer to your question then . . . -- i.e., that option may not exist.

Comment: On macOS, I installed 'gls' (GNU ls) and use `alias ls="gls -lh --time-style=long-iso | sort -fk8"` and `alias ll="gls -alh --time-style=long-iso | sort -fk8"` in `.bashrc`. This gives the right sorting in the terminal. One can use `gls` in dired-mode via `(setq insert-directory-program "gls" dired-use-ls-dired t)`, but it doesn't accept the `| sort -fk8`.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following in my `.emacs`:

```
(require 'ls-lisp)
(setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program nil)
(setq ls-lisp-ignore-case 't)
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Capitalized filenames still display first.

Comment: While this may work for users of Windows systems, it may not work for linux / unix systems -- e.g., OSX.  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/ls-in-Lisp.html

Comment: I've updated my response - Unix making you work harder, as always. I can't speak for a proper Unix but this certainly works on OS X with emacs 24.4.50.1. (I'm really not sure why this isn't the default on OS X, come to think of it, as its default filing system is case-insensitive...)

Comment: If you invoked that code after visiting a Dired buffer, then hit `g` after invoking it. IOW, revert the buffer, so it picks up the new settings.

Comment: Sadly, doesn't work for me on OSX El Capitan, Emacs 25.1.1.

Comment: Hm. I added `(setq ls-lisp-use-string-collate nil)`, this fixes sorting. It's a new variable introduced in Emacs 25.1.